# Bijection from set of bounded real-valued functions B(X) to $\mathbb R^{n}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $B(X)$ be the set of bounded real valued functions on the set X. And let X be the finite set $\{1,...,n\}$.

I have to find a bijection between $B(X)$ and $\mathbb R^{n}$, however I'm struggling to understand say, what is $B(1)$? For example.

The way I'm trying to think of it is, I am trying to find a function $\phi$, which takes $n$ bounded real function to the reals. $$\phi: B(X) \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n}, f \rightarrow \phi(f) = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$$ with $f = \{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}\in B(X)$ and $a_i\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: $B(\{1,...,n\}) $ consists of all real valued functions on $\{1,...,n\}$. Such functions are completely described by the tuple $(f(1),...,f(n))$. Define $\phi(f) = (f(1),...,f(n))$.

Comment: All functions on a finite set are bounded. Then, in your case, you have to establish a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^X$ (all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$) and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $X=\{x_1,\cdots , x_n\}$ ...

Comment: $B(1)$ Is nothing, really. It simply does not make sense: for B(something) to make sense, the something ha to be a set.

Comment: As for your proposal: it also does not make sense. You are trying to define a function $\phi$ on the set B(X), and therefore its arguments have to be elements of B(X). A general suggestion: every single time you write something, make extra sure that it actually means something — this is what computer people call "has a type". It is surprisingly amazing how far you can go if you limit yourself to writing only things that make sense.